# Return Value from Dropdown with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a drop down with the below code. The form is filled out when I load the webpage. I'd like to return the value that is already selected and assign it to a Python variable. I am getting the error: `TypeError: get_attribute() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

HTML:

```
<select id="TimeZone" name="TimeZoneTable"  size="1">   
    <option value="EST">Eastern Standard Time</option>
    <option value="Central">Central Time</option>
    <option value="Mountain">Mountain Time</option>
</select>
```

PYTHON:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('someurl.com')
driver.get_element_by_ID
value = driver.find_element_by_name("TimeZoneTable").get_attribute()
print value
```

Comment: `driver.get_element_by_ID` is doing nothing in your code.

Comment: `get_attribute()` most likely takes an the name of the attribute you want as an argument, which you are not supplying.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_name("TimeZoneTable").get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: This is great, but what if I want to return the text instead?

Comment: what exactly do you want to get `.getText()`?

Comment: Yes I want to return Eastern Standard Time.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because get_attribute method takes 1 variable and fetch the value associate with that variable.

```
value_size = driver.find_element_by_name("TimeZoneTable").get_attribute('size')
value_id = driver.find_element_by_name("TimeZoneTable").get_attribute('id')
```

value_size has the value assigned to 'size' attribute now.

If you want to fetch the first selected option, here is the way :

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

time_zone_obj = driver.find_element_by_id('TimeZone')
options_time_zone = Select(time_zone_obj)
selected_text = options_time_zone.first_selected_option.text
print ">>> selected option is %s"%(selected_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code in Java. It might help. Use Select for choosing the options.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("Your URL");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("TimeZone")); 

Select options = new Select(element);
options.selectByValue("Central"); //Choose EST etc in place of Central
```